# Extrapolating 100% in fill stacked plot

Tags: r, ggplot2

I have the following dataset:

```
temp_dt <- data.table(value = c(1295, 105, 66, 30),
                      A = c('done', 'remaining', 'done', 'remaining'),
                      B = c('type 1', 'type 1', 'type 2', 'type 2'))
> temp_dt
   value         A      B
1:  1295      done type 1
2:   105 remaining type 1
3:    66      done type 2
4:    30 remaining type 2
```

Where in type 1 the values must sum to 1400 and in type 2 the values must sum to 96, so if I increase the "done" the "remaining" must decrease in the same value.

I can plot the stacked percentage plot:

```
temp_dt %>% ggplot(aes(x = B, y = value, fill = A)) +
  geom_bar(stat = 'identity', position = position_fill(reverse = TRUE)) +
  coord_flip() + 
  geom_text(aes(label = round(value)), position = position_fill(reverse = TRUE, vjust = 0.5)) +
  scale_y_continuous(labels = scales::percent)
```

[image: initial plot]

So far, so good.

Now here comes the problem, there will be times when my work done will be greater than the estipulated ("done" + "remaining"), so the "remaining" column will become negative. Is there a way to make my scale extrapolate the 100% for both bars when at least one of them have negative remainings?

For example, if my dataset was changed to the one below:

```
temp_dt <- data.table(value = c(1295, 105, 120, -24),
                      A = c('done', 'remaining', 'done', 'remaining'),
                      B = c('type 1', 'type 1', 'type 2', 'type 2'))
> temp_dt
   value         A      B
1:  1295      done type 1
2:   105 remaining type 1
3:   120      done type 2
4:   -24 remaining type 2
```

I would like a plot like this one (made in Excel):

[image: desired plot]

Where the percentage scale would auto-adjust if my "done" column would be so great that the "remaining" would start to be negative.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think something like this should cover either eventuality:

```r
temp_dt %>% 
  group_by(B) %>%
  mutate(max = ifelse(B == "type 1", 1400, 96)) %>%
  mutate(percent = ifelse(value/max < 0, 0, value/max)) %>%
  mutate(A = factor(A, levels = c("remaining", "done")),
         B = factor(B, levels = c("type 2", 'type 1'))) %>%
  mutate(lab_pos = cumsum(percent) - percent/2) %>%
  ggplot(aes(x = B, y = percent, fill = A)) +
  geom_col(position = "stack", width = 0.6) +
  scale_fill_manual(values = c("red", "forestgreen")) +
  coord_flip() + 
  geom_text(aes(y = lab_pos, label = ifelse(value < 0, NA, round(value))), 
            colour = "white") +
  scale_y_continuous(labels = scales::percent, 
                     breaks = function(x) seq(0, max(x), 0.25)) +
  theme_bw()
```

With first data set:

[image]

---

With second data set:

[image]

Comment: Hi, do you see any way to put that 120 you got in the second dataset in the middle of the bar? Increasing hjust for it when having negative remainings, but keeping it the same when in a case like the first dataset?

Comment: Great! I tried to use an ifelse in the position argument of geom_text, changing hjust depending on value, but it didn't work and I don't know why.